# Convert Realm from Swift 4 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, realm, swift4

Im using Realm Database for iOS app development purpose,I have opened my project in Xcode 9.So every module automatically converted to Swift 4.When I opened my project in Xcode 8.2 the realm module which i'm using is giving me an alert [image: I just want to continue my work in Xcode 8.2 itself.any solution?]

Comment: change  Realm pod version for xcode 8.2.

Comment: because your RealmSwift.framework was built with newer swift compiler : 4.0.2

just rebuild it with Swift compiler 3.1 then you can use with xcode 8.2...